# Only printing words with certain characters in a string

Tags: java, string, for-loop, split

Here's my code. If the user's input is "Avery is into Naval Aviation" then I'm needing it to print out ONLY the words with "av" in them. What am I missing here?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {

        String user = scanner.nextLine();


        if (user.equals("")) {
            break;
        }

        String[] cut = user.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < cut.length; i++) {
            if (user.contains("av")) {
                System.out.println(cut[i]);
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Desired output:

Avery
Naval
Aviation

Comment: Try `cut[i].contains("av")`

Comment: ... and `user.toLowerCase().split(" ")`

Comment: Just a suggestion - use an enhanced for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You are checking `user` whether it contains `av` whereas you need to check `cut[i]`.
2. You are checking for `av` which is in lower case, therefore you need to check `av` in lowercased `cut[i]`.

## Solution:

Replace

```
user.contains("av")
```

with

```
cut[i].toLowerCase().contains("av")
```

Alternatively, you can split lowercased `user` and then search `av` into the resulting array i.e.

```
String[] cut = user.toLowerCase().split(" ");
```

and then, you can use

```
cut[i].contains("av")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you are referencing the `user` parameter in the loop instead of the `word` you want to search for
2. there might also be upper case / lower case mismatch.
3. You might also need to split based on regex and not simply space.

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

   ```
   while (true) {

       String user = scanner.nextLine();


       if (user.equals("")) {
           break;
       }

       String[] words = user.toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
       for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
           if (words[i].contains("av")) {
               System.out.println(cut[i]);
           }


       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong variable in the marked line:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) 
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );

    while( true ) 
    {
        String user = scanner.nextLine();

        if( user.equals( "" ) ) break;

        String[] cut = user.toLowerCase().split( " " );
        for( int i = 0; i < cut.length; ++i ) 
        {
            if( cut [i].contains( "av" ) ) /* originally: user.contains(…) */ 
            {
                System.out.println( cut[i] );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what [The fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird) meant with their comment.

And the call to `String.toLowerCase()` makes sure that "Avery" and "Aviation" are found, too, if this is desired (mine and [Andreas'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) assumption – see comment).

You can of course use an enhanced for loop or even a `Stream`, but that is more or less a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with your idea of using `String.split` you would do something like this:

```
String test = "Avery is into Naval Aviation";

for(String word : test.split(" "))
    if(word.toLowerCase().contains("av"))
        System.out.println(word);
```

However, another option to consider is using a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to do the matching:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]*av[a-z]*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
for(Matcher m = p.matcher(test); m.find();)
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

Output:

```
Avery
Naval
Aviation
```